# Why the value from mysql database is not set as "selected" in the dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, variables

This does not reflect the data that's on the database. I don't know why, but the other dropdowns work properly except this. This one has 2 conditions for the WHERE clause that is working. The one that's not working is the selection of the data according to that one saved in the database. Again, I also have other 2 dropdowns which is these that's working..

```
<font> Course/Year/Section</font>

<?php
$sqlA = "SELECT Course FROM tblcys";
$resultA = mysql_query($sqlA);

echo "<select name='Course' required>";
echo "<option value=''>Select Course</option>";
while ($rw = mysql_fetch_array($resultA)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rw['Course']; ?>"<?php if($rw['Course']==$Course) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $rw['Course']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
echo "</select>" ?>

<?php
$sqlB = "SELECT Year FROM tblcys WHERE Course ='". $Course. "' ORDER BY Year ASC";
$resultB = mysql_query($sqlB);

echo "<select name='Year' required>";
echo "<option value=''>Select Year</option>";
while ($rw1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultB)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rw1['Year']; ?>"<?php if($rw1['Year']==$Year) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $rw1['Year']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
```

This one is the one that's not working

```
<?php
$sqlC = "SELECT Section FROM tblcys WHERE tblcys.Course ='". $Course. "' AND tblcys.Year ='". $Year. "' ORDER BY Section ASC";
$resultC = mysql_query($sqlC);

echo "<select name='Section' required>";
echo "<option value=''>Select Section</option>";
while ($rw2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultC)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rw2['Section']; ?>"<?php if($rw2['Section']==$Section) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $rw2['Section']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
echo "</select>" ?>
```

These are the other details about the variables being passed on.

```
$result2=mysql_query("Select * From tblrecord where studID='$ID'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{

$RFIDNo=$row['RFIDNo'];
$studID=$row['studID'];
$lname=$row['lname'];
$fname=$row['fname'];
$mi=$row['mi'];
$Course=$row['Course'];
$Year=$row['Year'];
$Section=$row['Section'];
$Section=$row['Status'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

`$Section=$row['Status'];`

It should be

`$Status=$row['Status'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the table reference from the statement:

```
$sqlC = "SELECT Section FROM tblcys WHERE tblcys.Course ='". $Course. "' AND tblcys.Year ='". $Year. "' ORDER BY Section ASC";
```

to

```
$sqlC = "SELECT Section FROM tblcys WHERE Course ='". $Course. "' AND Year ='". $Year. "' ORDER BY Section ASC";
```

Comment: That's the first one I've done and it's not working. I tried it again now but still not working. Anyways, I guess this should not be the problem since I can see the filtered results as option in the selectbox. My problem is the data in the mysqlDB to be reflected in the dropdown. For example if Section is "C" then "C" should be the "default" or "selected" in the dropdown. With the same syntax for the three, I don't understand why the last one is not working.